# JSF Dialog Return in Composite Component with Primefaces Select Event not finding method in Bean

Tags: java, jpa, jsf, primefaces, xhtml

I'm trying to create a default component for my project, which consists of a component with a button for a custom search in a separate modal, and a function that receives the SelectEvent for treating the value that the user selected, and setting that value somewhere else in my bean. The problem is that the composite component is not finding the method for the dialog return of the ajax.

**My composite component which is named inputConverter.xhtml**

```xml
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"   
      xmlns:composite = "http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <composite:interface>
        <composite:attribute name = "labelValue" required="true"/>
        <composite:attribute name = "inputId" required="true"/>
        <composite:attribute name = "inputValue" required="true"/>
        <composite:attribute name = "inputObject" required="true"/>                        
        <composite:attribute name = "limpaAction" method-signature="void limpaAction()" required="true"/>
        <composite:attribute name = "buscaAction" method-signature="void buscaAction()" required="true"/>
        <composite:attribute name = "retornoAction" method-signature="void retornoAction(org.primefaces.event.SelectEvent)" />
                                                                                                                                        
    </composite:interface>

    <composite:implementation>
        <p:panelGrid columns="1">
            <p:outputLabel for="@next" value="#{cc.attrs.labelValue}"/>

            <p:panelGrid columns="3" styleClass="ui-inputgroup">
                <p:inputText value="#{cc.attrs.inputValue}" readonly="true"/>
                
                <p:commandButton action="#{cc.attrs.limpaAction}" rendered="#{not empty cc.attrs.inputObject}" update="@parent" icon="pi pi-trash" styleClass="ui-button-danger"/>
                <p:commandButton action="#{cc.attrs.buscaAction}" icon="pi pi-search" styleClass="ui-button-info" >
                    <p:ajax event="dialogReturn" listener="#{cc.attrs.retornoAction}" update="@parent"/>
                </p:commandButton>
            </p:panelGrid>
        </p:panelGrid>
    </composite:implementation>
</html>
```

**The way I'm calling it in my main xhtml**

```html
<custom:inputConverter 
    labelValue="País"                                
    inputObject="#{pacienteBean.paciente.paisNacionalidade}"
    inputId="#{pacienteBean.paciente.paisNacionalidade.id}"
    inputValue="#{pacienteBean.paciente.paisNacionalidade.nome}"
    buscaAction="#{pacienteBean.buscaNacionalidade}"
    retornoAction="#{pacienteBean.selecionaNacionalidade}"
    limpaAction="#{pacienteBean.limpaNacionalidade}"
/>
```

**The method in my bean which I'm trying to call in the composite component**

```java
public void selecionaNacionalidade(SelectEvent<Pais> e) {
    objetoCrud.setPaisNacionalidade(e.getObject());
}
```

The problem is that the composite component is not finding my method through the composite attribute, but when I try to call **#{pacienteBean.selecionaNacionalidade}** directly in the composite component it works, I've also tried changing the method-signature of retornoAction in many ways and it did not work. The error that I get when I select something in the search dialog is the following:

```
17-Nov-2022 19:57:12.950 ADVERTÃŠNCIA [http-nio-8080-exec-87] com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ContextualCompositeMethodExpression.invoke javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: Method not found: beans.PacienteBean@10418122.selecionaNacionalidade()
17-Nov-2022 19:57:12.951 ADVERTÃŠNCIA [http-nio-8080-exec-87] com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ContextualCompositeMethodExpression.invoke jsf.facelets.el.method.expression.invoke.error: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /cadastros/cadastroPacientes.xhtml @69,35 retornoAction="#{pacienteBean.selecionaNacionalidade}": Property [selecionaNacionalidade] not found on type [beans.PacienteBean] #{pacienteBean.selecionaNacionalidade}
17-Nov-2022 19:57:12.951 ADVERTÃŠNCIA [http-nio-8080-exec-87] com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ApplyRequestValuesPhase.execute /cadastros/cadastroPacientes.xhtml @69,35 retornoAction="#{pacienteBean.selecionaNacionalidade}": Property [selecionaNacionalidade] not found on type [beans.PacienteBean]
    javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /cadastros/cadastroPacientes.xhtml @69,35 retornoAction="#{pacienteBean.selecionaNacionalidade}": Property [selecionaNacionalidade] not found on type [beans.PacienteBean]
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:117)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ContextualCompositeMethodExpression.invoke(ContextualCompositeMethodExpression.java:218)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.TagAttributeImpl$AttributeLookupMethodExpression.invoke(TagAttributeImpl.java:480)
        at org.primefaces.behavior.ajax.AjaxBehaviorListenerImpl.processAjaxBehavior(AjaxBehaviorListenerImpl.java:71)
        at org.primefaces.event.AbstractAjaxBehaviorEvent.processListener(AbstractAjaxBehaviorEvent.java:48)
        at javax.faces.component.behavior.BehaviorBase.broadcast(BehaviorBase.java:106)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:830)
        at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:835)
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processDecodes(UIViewRoot.java:1034)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ApplyRequestValuesPhase.execute(ApplyRequestValuesPhase.java:79)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:201)
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:670)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:543)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:698)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:367)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:639)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:882)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1693)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
    Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property [selecionaNacionalidade] not found on type [beans.PacienteBean]
        at javax.el.BeanELResolver$BeanProperties.get(BeanELResolver.java:267)
        at javax.el.BeanELResolver$BeanProperties.access$300(BeanELResolver.java:219)
        at javax.el.BeanELResolver.property(BeanELResolver.java:340)
        at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:101)
        at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:180)
        at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:208)
        at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:168)
        at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:189)
        at org.jboss.weld.module.web.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:115)
        ... 35 more
17-Nov-2022 19:57:13.131 GRAVE [http-nio-8080-exec-87] com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.handlePartialResponseError javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /cadastros/cadastroPacientes.xhtml @69,35 retornoAction="#{pacienteBean.selecionaNacionalidade}": Property [selecionaNacionalidade] not found on type [beans.PacienteBean]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:117)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ContextualCompositeMethodExpression.invoke(ContextualCompositeMethodExpression.java:218)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.TagAttributeImpl$AttributeLookupMethodExpression.invoke(TagAttributeImpl.java:480)
    at org.primefaces.behavior.ajax.AjaxBehaviorListenerImpl.processAjaxBehavior(AjaxBehaviorListenerImpl.java:71)
    at org.primefaces.event.AbstractAjaxBehaviorEvent.processListener(AbstractAjaxBehaviorEvent.java:48)
    at javax.faces.component.behavior.BehaviorBase.broadcast(BehaviorBase.java:106)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:830)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:835)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processDecodes(UIViewRoot.java:1034)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ApplyRequestValuesPhase.execute(ApplyRequestValuesPhase.java:79)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:201)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:670)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:543)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:698)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:367)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:639)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:882)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1693)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property [selecionaNacionalidade] not found on type [beans.PacienteBean]
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver$BeanProperties.get(BeanELResolver.java:267)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver$BeanProperties.access$300(BeanELResolver.java:219)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.property(BeanELResolver.java:340)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:180)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:208)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:168)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:189)
    at org.jboss.weld.module.web.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:115)
    ... 35 more
```

I'm using JSF 2.3 with Primefaces 10.0.0.

**Edit:** Found a workaround for solving this issue, if you want to see more of the source code you can look it at: https://github.com/guilhermepereira2917/SettingMusicoterapia.

Added the following remote command on **inputConverter.xhtml**:

```html
<p:remoteCommand name="#{cc.id}" action="#{cc.attrs.retornoAction}" immediate="true"/>
```

Switched dialog return ajax of **inputConverter.xhtml** for calling:

```html
<p:ajax event="dialogReturn" listener="#{buscaBean.resultadoPesquisaInputConverter}"
        oncomplete="#{cc.id}()"/>
```

Created the session scoped bean **BuscaBean.java** with the following attribute and method:

```java
public static <T> void resultadoPesquisaInputConverter(SelectEvent<T> event) {
    objetoSelecionado = event.getObject();
}
```

And grabbed the selected object of the dialog through the called method of the remote command:

```java
@Inject
private BuscaBean buscaBean;

public void selecionaNacionalidade() {
    objetoCrud.setPaisNacionalidade(buscaBean.getResultadoPesquisa(Pais.class));
}
```

And the way I use my input converter at the end looks like this:

```html
<custom:inputConverter 
    labelValue="País"                                
    inputObject="#{pacienteBean.paciente.paisNacionalidade}"
    inputId="#{pacienteBean.paciente.paisNacionalidade.id}"
    inputValue="#{pacienteBean.paciente.paisNacionalidade.nome}"
    buscaAction="#{buscaBean.abrirBuscaPaises}"
    retornoAction="#{pacienteBean.selecionaNacionalidade}"
    limpaAction="#{pacienteBean.limpaNacionalidade}"
    />
```

Comment: Did you solve the problem

Comment: I was not able to solve the problem the way I wanted and unfortunately had to do a workaround using a session bean. Are you interested in the source code?

Comment: I am facing the same problem right now. I would appreciate if you share your solution

Comment: I edited the post trying to explain what I did differently, but there are more irrelevant parts for this problem that I tried to hide (you can take a look at those on the repository I linked). I hope this works for you, send me a message if you managed to solve it or have any questions!

Comment: By using org.primefaces.event.AbstractAjaxBehaviorEvent instead of org.primefaces.event.SelectEvent, the object no longer throws a NullPointerException but continues to warn. Although it gives a warning, it works as a result. I am using it this way for now. https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/10777 I could not get a solution.